# building hadoop using maven+eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, hadoop

I'm trying to build hadoop using eclipse mvn plugin (i.e. m2e). However, the build process fails due to a dependency resolution problem and gives the following error message:

```
Failed to execute goal on project hadoop-common: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.8, javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1, tomcat:jasper-compiler:jar:5.5.23, commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0, commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0, org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.8, com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3, org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.3.2: Could not transfer artifact com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.8 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000 -> [Help 1]
```

Now, what should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Maven.

You'll find a solution originally posted by `Jonas Andersson` in response to [Maven error “Failure to transfer…”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer):

Remove all your failed downloads:

```
find ~/.m2  -name "*.lastUpdated" -exec grep -q "Could not transfer" {} \; -print -exec rm {} \;
```

Then rightclick on your project in eclipse and choose Maven->Update Dependencies

**Again, all credit goes to Jonas Andersson here.**

Comment: thanks, but my Maven menu has no 'update dependencies' or 'update snapshots' item