# error in pom.xml in creating dynamic projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

When I am trying to create any project using maven in eclipse pom.xml always has a red cross with below message:

```
Failure to transfer xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
```

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer

Comment: Please post your maven pom.xml