# Maven Error - Failure to Transfer

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm looking into some spring examples on net. I got one example from

http://code.google.com/p/spring-finance-manager/

While importing the project in my eclipse,I got error in POM.xml file.

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
 local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer 
 artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://
 repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom
- connection timed out
- Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:pom:2.0.4 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
 local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer 
 artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:pom:2.0.4 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to 
 http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-source-plugin/2.0.4/maven-source-plugin-2.0.4.pom
```

I also tried by deleting my .m2\repository folder. But still getting the error.

Can anyone guide me to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have experienced this issue myself. Here are a few other observations:

1. Previously when I had this error, I would go to Maven -> Update Maven Project and if this does not work, Maven -> Update Maven Project and "Force Update of snapshots/releases." This technique would work.
2. After a while, #1 above stopped working. However, when I built the same project in the same workspace without the proxy, it worked.
3. Applying settings.xml with proxy information does not solve this specific problem stated below:

> Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to
>   central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out

I am also wondering what this actually means: what exactly is being transferred and from where to where? I believe we have .pom files initially in our workspaces and based on the pom, the necessary artifacts will be downloaded to our local maven repositories. These repositories are further referred to in our IDE build path.

Why is it that it "times out" for certain artifacts and not for others? Also, these things seem to point to "org.eclipse.m2.core." To be more precise, the combination of org.eclipse.m2.core and proxy is screwing it up -- which as developers we have no control over. It is very frustrating.

What we do not know can seriously hurt us -- case in point -- (eclipse + proxy) dynamics.

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the solution after some heavy googling: in addition to adding proxy information in the settings.xml, I also had to add the following to make the problem go away. Once again, this is a problem only when there is a proxy involved. This is the calm before the next eclipse related cryptic stack trace vomit -- I guess.

```
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>securecentral</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>securecentral</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a timeout exception requesting http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 repository. Time to time  http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 not working properly. Also possible other network problems, like your hosts dns, network broken hub, network proxy settings etc...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issues in many different networks, that's not normally happening because of your internet or network, that's the issue with Maven repo , as a solution I cleaned up my local .m repo directory and download the jar files again via maven / update the maven dependencies. 
the issue will be gone. and that's just one time process, don't need to do it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the settings.xml file for maven which contains userid and password information to connect to the repository. The settings.xml file contains information like this -

```
<repository>
<id>your_nexus_repo_id</id>
<url>https://path_to_nexus_repo_location</url>
<releases>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</releases>
<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>
</repository>

<server>
  <id>dsnexus1</id>
      <username>your_user_id</username>
       <password>your_password</password>
</server>
```

You can provide the settings.xml file in Eclipse like this -

1. In Eclipse IDE, go to Windows >> Preferences >> Maven >> User Settings
2. Provide settings.xml in "User Settings" input box by using the Browse Button. 
   Your settings.xml file should be located in /user-home/.m2/ folder.

After this -

1. Right Click on your project
2. Go to - Maven >> Update Project
3. Click "Force update" so that you will get the latest copies of the snapshot releases

Now, Build your project -

1. Right click your projet
2. Go to Run As >> Maven Build
3. Provide Goals: "clean install"
4. Click Run

This should solve your problem :)