# Constant ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer even after deleting m2/repository and/or *.lastUpdate

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, m2eclipse

I'm trying to build my maven project using Spring tool suite, and I'm constantly getting ArtifactTransfer exception even after removing .m2/repository directory and/or applying this fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7108536/1178798

I've tried running spring as an administrator, and on two different networks. I also tried reinstalling STS, nothing has helped so far. Firewall is disabled... Any ideas?

Thank you.

**EDIT #1** Link to pastebin with few of these errors (notice that there are not all of the errors since I couldn't select all 95 of them, and I didn't want to copy paste each one individually)

Link: http://pastebin.com/4QS3G90K

Comment: Have you verified the artifact exists in the repository you are connecting to? (And what is the root cause of the ArtifactTransferException?)

Comment: Artifact does exist in the repository, the same project builds on my work machine, but not on my personal machine. The exception says: Failure to transfer org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0 (Click for 95 more). Yes you read it right, 95 of those exceptions...

Comment: Can you paste the full error message and not only exerpts..

Comment: The question has been updated with link to pastebin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but it looks like the problem was my ISP. After connecting to VPN service I was able to successfully download all artifacts and start my project without any errors.

I hope this helps someone out there, so they don't waste couple of days searching for such trivial solution to not-so trivial problem.

PS: you can use free VPN services, you don't have to buy subscription.