# DHIS2 - Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.hisp.dhis

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

It will sound like duplicate, but I am having a bit problem

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.hisp.dhis:dhis:pom:2.18-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' 
>        points at wrong local POM
>
> Project build error: 'parent.relativePath' points at org.hisp.dhis:dhis-local instead of org.hisp.dhis:dhis, please verify your project structure

Here is the part of `POM.xml` where I am getting error:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.hisp.dhis</groupId>
    <artifactId>dhis</artifactId>
    <version>2.18-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
```

I have followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7108536/3141985) to remove the failed dependencies.

Can someone explain, what action is required to resolve this issue?

Thanks