# Spring-MVC-Maven-Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.0.1

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

*i created my spring-maven project with spring and other dependencies in maven pom.xml file and the project has been build-ed and run successfully  after some days i tried to update dependencies and build the project again  this failure occurred !*

any help please ?

> **Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.0.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.0.1 from/to central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after
>   60000 pom.xml /DeabrnyRack**
>
> **updated**:**i found the solution in this thread as there is updated
>   versions of dependencies made conflict so i removed the
>   "plexus-archiver.lastupdated" link :**
>   [Maven error "Failure to transfer..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer)

Comment: What did you actually change in your POM? can you post it, removing any sensitive/non-shareable details? Running with -U option does it get any better?

Comment: what do you mean about removing any sensitive/non-shareable details ?Running with -U option does it get any better?   @A.DiMatteo

Comment: well you may have something you don't want to share with the world :) just for saying. Ok, then I guess you can post your POM. about the -U, I meant from the console executing: mvn clean install -U

Comment: ok,thank u for advise but i don't use the console and i found the solution here

Comment: the solution here and i will update the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer