# Maven unable to resolve Vaadin addon dependency

Tags: java, maven, vaadin

I have the following entry for repositories in maven....

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
```

With the following dependency...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.addon</groupId>
        <artifactId>confirmdialog</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I go to build the app I see this...

[WARNING] The POM for org.vaadin.addon:confirmdialog:jar:2.1.3 is missing, no dependency information available

According to the Vaadin directory I should be able to add this dependency with those two entries...  I have used this in previous projects.  Perhaps is the Vaadin addons repo down?

https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/confirmdialog

Comment: Have you tried nuking your `.m2` folder and retrying? The configuration you have works fine for me. It might also be a problem in your Maven proxy, if you're using any.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was our corporate firewall keeping me "safe".  It filtered Maven traffic as "dangerous".

Answer (score 0):

The file is definitely available in the Vaadin repo at the specificed coordinates.

http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons/org/vaadin/addon/confirmdialog/2.1.3/confirmdialog-2.1.3.jar

Before nuking your `.m2` repo you may want to force an update. Previous failed attempts to find the dependency would have been cached in your local repo. This forces Maven to try again in those cases.

```
mvn -U clean package
```

In general I think nuking the `.m2` repo is not a good idea. At the very least you can be more surgical and delete the directories related to the dependency having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like provided repository and its dependency is avalible.

Try removing previously failed dependency downloads in your .m2 folder eg. "*.lastUpdated" files with:

```
find ~/.m2  -name "*.lastUpdated" -exec grep -q "Could not transfer" {} \; -print -exec rm {} \;
```

For Windows:

```
cd %userprofile%\.m2\repository
for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i
```

[Maven error "Failure to transfer..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer)