# Getting error in pom.xml. It shows connection timed out. My network proxy does not allow to connect to Maven

Tags: java, json, eclipse, maven

When I was trying to use Maven in my project, I got the below error building:

> CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.5.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.5.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.5.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven error "Failure to transfer..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer)

Comment: You have the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer

Answer (score 2):

Your connection has timed out - make sure that you are connected to the internet (e.g. try `ping repo.maven.apache.org` from your command line). If you are behind a proxy server you'll have to add configuration accordingly (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html).

Once you have made sure that your internet connection works you can force maven to reattempt the transfer by appending the `-U` flag to your command.

Comment: I tried the command ping repo.maven.apache.org. It says Request timed out.

Comment: Then I suggest you check your internet connection / proxy settings.