# Creating Maven Project in Eclipse Neon2 encountred a issue : Could not resolve archetype

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am trying to create a maven project. But it is throwing following Error.

> "Could not resolve archetype
>
> > org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 from any of the
> >     configured repositories. Could not resolve artifact
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 Failure to
> >     transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0
> >     from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
> >     repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
> >     interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
> >     Could not transfer artifact
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to
> >     central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
> >     Failure to transfer
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from
> >     https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
> >     repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
> >     interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
> >     Could not transfer artifact
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to
> >     central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out"

Attached Image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem before. I found the solution from this [Maven error "Failure to transfer..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer), hope it can help you.

Anurak Th.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem removing `.m2` folder from `C:\Users\{user name}\.m2`. Then recreate your maven project and right click on your project > maven > update project.
Initially, maven looks for libraries and dependencies in the local repository. In case, they are not in its local repository it will look for the remote ones. But in this case, it didn't look for the remote repository. So need to update the project for future conditions.