# New Eclipse Maven Project Proxy (timeout?)

Tags: eclipse, maven, proxy, timeout

I have an problem here with Maven.
I can't create new project, get the error message at once.

```
"Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from ..ps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact ..g.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (..ps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from ..ps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (..tps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out"
```

what I have tried:
create new settings.xml with proxy

```
 <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>proxyidhere</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.here.de</host>
      <port>theporthere</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.here.de|localhost</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

also tried

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>proxyidhere</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpConfiguration>
          <put>
            <connectionTimeout>120000</connectionTimeout> 
          </put>
        </httpConfiguration>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

and also in eclipse.ini:

```
-Dhttp.proxyPort=theporthere
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.here.de
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

also

General->Network Connections
    Proxy entries provider manual
    HTTP
    HTTPS socks...

have no idea at the moment

the proxy is a also an problem for Help->install new Software

"fechting children of mars" pending....need >20 sec

I am using mars2
I've also tried it with neon2
it is even worst, also timeout on install new software after ~60sec

```
"fechting children of neon" 

"Unable to connect to repository ...download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/content.xml
Unable to connect to repository ...download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/content.xml
Connection timed out: connect"
```

any ideas?

edit:
what ports do I need for maven to work?
maybe it's an fw/network issue

Comment: solved with this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer
just delete *.lastupdate