# Maven : Installed the Maven Plugin in eclipse but POM.xml has some error

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

I have installed the Maven Plugin in eclipse successfully and generated the POM.xml in eclipse but POM.xml is giving some errors,

**my POM.xml :**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SeleniumApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

**Errors are showing :**

***CoreException:

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.5.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.5.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.5.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out

Any help on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven error "Failure to transfer..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer)

Comment: can you please try in your cmd `mvn eclipse:eclipse` then refresh your project

Comment: Its not working. Actually POM.xml is not getting generated properly.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0rc2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem, POM.xml is **not Configured** properly

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>SeleniumApp</groupId>
 <artifactId>SeleniumApp</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <name>SeleniumApp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0rc2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```