# Maven dependency for javax.mail

Tags: maven

What is the maven dependency i should add for

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
```

Adding the maven dependency from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.5.0-b01 makes some of the jersey dependencies unable to retrieve error. What do you think is going wrong?

Comment: The correct answer to this depends upon whether or not you are deploying to a Java EE server, servlet container or building a standalone application.

Comment: I am deploying it to a tomcat server

Comment: In that case @MitulGedeeya 's answer is appropriate, although I'd use version 1.5.6. The linked solution to your download problem is a bit severe though - you normally just need to append `-U` to your maven command line to fix the cached failure problem. In any event that is a different question

Comment: @SteveC You are right. Sometimes it won't take dependency from maven but instead it uses cache. So, by putting -U must resolve problem.

Comment: @BalajiVignesh Hello, Let us inform whether you resolved problem or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are using following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am getting this error on adding  com.sun.mail. ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.2: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer com.sun.mail:javax.mail:pom:1.5.2 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.sun.mail:javax.mail:pom:1.5.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

Comment: For that Error [This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer) will resolve your issue.

Comment: Or You can just check whether in .m2 folder, there will be cached dependency available. just remove that folder and update project.

Comment: I have tried removing the folder in the .m2 but facing the same error

Comment: Hmm. for last time can you please check with the any fixed version of dependency i have given in answer? because we are using the same and our project works.

Answer (score 5):

The version 1.6.3 had been the last version of *JavaMail*; since 2019-07-03, the new name for it is "Jakarta Mail".

Together with the name change also the Maven coordinates got different:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
  <version>…</version>
</dependency>
```

The project homepage can be found here: [<strike>https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/</strike>](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/) https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.mail

Comment: just to follow up, with the latest version as for now it'll look like this:              <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.1</version>

Comment: Latest version is now 2.1.2 (released 2023-05-05