# Spring Boot and JSP not rendering

Tags: jsp, spring-boot

I've been working on this for days trying to get it to work.  Trying to use JSP with Spring Boot.  I've been following the example at [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp).  So many examples on the web have a web.xml file, yet the example on github, which is referenced many times on this forum, doesn't even have a web.xml. Also, when creating a Spring Boot Project, STS doesn't create a "webapp" directory with subdirectory "WEB-INF". I had to create those manually in Windows Explorer then refresh Project Explorer in STS to make them appear.

Regardless, I have followed the example as best I can but still can't get my index.jsp file to render in the browser when I type in http://localhost:8080 in the address field.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far. 
Directory structure:

[image]

application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jeddatae_editor
spring.datasource.username=webapp
spring.datasource.password=secret
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
  String name = request.getParameter("name");
%>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>JED Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/index" method="post">
<p>Insert ID here: <input type="text" id="id" name="id"></p>
<input type=submit>
</form>
<%
  if(!name.equals(""))
  {
%>
<div class="welcome">
  <p>Welcome <%=name %> </p><p>If you are not <%=name %>, then try a different id.</p>
</div>
<%
  }
%>
```

hello.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hello</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

GreetingController.java

```
package com.anypackage.jedcontext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;
import com.tacticalenterprisesltd.Database;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public RedirectView index(@RequestParam(value="id", required=false) String id, RedirectAttributes attribs) {        
        if (id != null)
        {
          Database db = new Database("jeddatae_editor");
          String[][] result = db.executeSelect("SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) FROM employees WHERE id=" + id + ";"); 
          if(result.length != 0){
            attribs.addAttribute("name", result[0][0]);
          }        
        }        

        return new RedirectView("index");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {

        return "hello";
    } 
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.anypackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>jedtest</name>
    <description>An application context test</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>         
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Tomcat embedded container-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>            
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>           
        </dependency>

    </dependencies> 

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: spring-boot projects never creates a webapp directory by default. do you get any error message?

Comment: JSPs are packaged into a "war" not "jar". You didn't follow at all the example in github

Comment: You spotted the problem in the pom.xml file. Great! I changed the packaging type to war, but doing so generated an error message which I have no idea how to fix.  Error:  Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:2.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

Comment: I did a search on the error and followed instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer  That seemed to help the project compile properly, however, when running the app, changing the packaging from jar to war didn't make any difference.  I'm still getting a status 404 in the browser.

Comment: One other thing happened when I change the packaging to type war.  As you can see from the Directory Structure picture, it now expects a web.xml file. So now I'm left scratching my head.  The github example specifically shows no web.xml, yet my project is now expecting me to include one.  Please advise.

Comment: I added another webpage named hello.jsp.  In the browser, if I type http://localhost:8080/hello then the hello.jsp page renders properly.  So why doesn't index.jsp not render???

Comment: Why do you use RedirectView? I mean, simply use String as a method return type, in your parameters use (Model model), add your attributes via model.addAttribute("stg", someobject); and return "index"

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon how you package your artifact as a war/jar file.

**War File Package following rules should be followed.**

1. Your main class should extend ***SpringBootServletInitializer***
2. You have to create a custom error.jsp page won’t override the default view for error handling, custom error pages should be used instead.
3. You run these ordinary maven goals like ***mvn clean install package -e*** and deploy it your in tomcat web server.

**JAR file Package**

4. It won't work as your embedded tomcat is using hard coded file pattern in tomcat.
5. Exactly follow this [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) and refactor your code accordingly.

   Please refer this [JSP Limitations with Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations).

Answer (score 1):

I think you first need to handle redirect. Because in your case `new RedirectView("index")` redirects to for example `/index?name=Alan`

Add method:

```
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String handleRedirect() {
        return "index";
    }
```

It should work if you run it as simple spring boot app:

> mvn spring-boot:run

But if you are going to deploy war file on app server don't forget to configure like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JedtestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(JedtestApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JedtestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
add this dependency to the pom.xml in spring boot and also place jsp files in src/main/resources/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp.... like this and configure it in application.properties as 
                             spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp
                             spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
It was solved for me.
```