# Fail to build zookeeper env by maven on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, apache-zookeeper

I try to use maven to build zookeeper project environment to test DistributedLock on eclipse ,here is the pom.xml, but something is wrong 
Tip:

*Failure to transfer org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:4.0.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.*
I don't know what it means
I tried this http://curator.apache.org/zk-compatibility.html but it didn't work.
can somebody know how to solve it?
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      4.0.0

```
  <groupId>Day0105ZK</groupId>
  <artifactId>Day0105ZK</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Day0105ZK</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-framework</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-recipes</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- something wrong on this dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.1</version>
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dependency seems ok and since the jar is avaliable on the maven-server it probably was a temporary problem.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer) to see how to remove the marker for the failed download and try again.