# maven project Could not resolve archetype

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to start a maven project on my eclipse IDE, and I'm getting this error message. I tried to add remote represents the http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml catalog file.But it didn't fix the error.
Please let

```
org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the 
configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype- 
quickstart:pom:1.1
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype- 
quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in t 
he local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could 
not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype- 
quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype- 
quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in 
the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could 
not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype- 
quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven
```

Comment: I solved the problem with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is going to help or not.
Use below commond for force update:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

-U -> Maven force update.

Answer (score 0):

You are inside a company network, right? Then the proxy or firewall blocks your access. Configure the right proxy for Maven or talk to your administrator.

Answer (score 0):

> PKIX path building failed: 
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
>   valid certification path to requested target

points to a problem with SSL. either the java you use has no valid CA certificates to validate the SSL certitificate from https://repo.maven.apache.org or your company firewall is highjacking each https traffic with an own certrificate - which then itself must be available in your javas truststore.

as [JF Meier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927493/jf-meier) said, you should contact your local admin in this case

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem "Could not resolve archetype... for quickstart"
I saw some archetypes to choose from with release numbers and some with only "RELEASES" in big letters.
I followed the written path with browser and found:
501 HTTPS Required.
Use https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
More information at https://links.sonatype.com/central/501-https-required
So they changed it to an https and you have to edit the path to reach the external Archetypes to the mentioned:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
This did it for me.
Possibly you have also to look for the presence and content of the
"settings.xml"
in "Users\yourUserName\.m2".

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)