# Why I cant create a new Spring boot project with STS IDE?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-tool-suite

This is my first Spring Boot project.
I Installed Spring Tool Suite IDE and when I try to create a new project! I Get these errors (as you can see on the GIF)

I tried with Java8 and Java11 and I still get the error.

The stack trace of the error:

> ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer
> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:pom:3.1.0 from
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
> repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
> interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
> Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:pom:3.1.0
> from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
> repo.maven.apache.org

The 4 errors:
[image]

I did  `cd %userprofile%\.m2\repository` on the cmd and then I did `start .` to open the folder, then I manually deleted the cache.

That solved the 4 errors above.
But I got 2 new warnings:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
First warning:

> Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-11. There are no
> JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this
> environment.

Second warning:

> The compiler compliance specified is 11 but a JRE 14 is
> used  produits

Image of the new warnings:
[image: enter image description here:]

When I open File-> Properties I got this :

[image]

Comment: Since it's based on Eclipse, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer might be related

Comment: sounds definitely like the issue mentioned in the previous comment, so please take a look and delete your local Maven cache.

Comment: I cleared the cache, and it solve those 4 errors .. but now I get 2 new warnings..  I edited my post!

Comment: check your pom.xml, what version is there and check compiler compliance, what is there? Both values should be same. Also in build path the same native library should be used.(JDK not JRE)

Comment: THe warnings about jre means Eclipse/STS cannot find a jvm of the version that your project is configured to use. All you have to do is add a jre of the right version to your workspace. Go to "Window >> Preferences" then type 'JRE' in the searchbox.

Comment: @Kris I edited the default path of the JRE to the folder of the `JDK D:\Java\JDK` and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Maybe Eclipse doesn't update the info about the JRE if you just change its path, that could be a bug. Try deleting the JRE in preference. Then add it back. Also, make sure the JDK you point to is actually a JDK 11 (from the path `D:\Java\JDK` I cannot tell what version it is)