# Cannot resolve symbol 'HtmlPage' , what dependency to add in pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I need to use below code to login to webpage using Java

> Cannot resolve symbol 'HtmlPage'

error with below code

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://www.valueresearchonline.com/login");

        final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("email");
        textField.setValueAttribute("jon@jon.com");
```

For `WebClient` added below dependancy in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.22</version>
        </dependency>
```

But not getting what other dependancies to be added for `HtmlPage` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got the wrong depency. You need:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.64.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You also should remove webflux and potentially generated imports.

Comment: you mean "htmlunit" is only thing needed for both WebClient & HtmlPage ?

Comment: net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:pom:2.64.0 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:pom:2.64.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit/2.64.0/htmlunit-2.64.0.pom

Comment: solved above problem with help of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer