# Maven error "Unknown lifecycle phase ".test.skip=true"....."

Tags: java, maven

when i try to install maven, i get this error in intellij, itried all the solution proposed here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer" but it doesn't work

```
PS C:\Users\stagiaire1\Desktop\Vgc\vgc-backend>  mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< com.dzadvisory:bankapp >-----------------------
[INFO] Building bankapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.344 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-21T16:51:00+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".test.skip=true". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phas
es are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-com
pile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]   
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Comment: try this   ->   mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true ,  I believe the command you're giving to skip test-case is wrong

Comment: i tried this command but i get the same error

Comment: do you have any settings.xml  in ur project ?  can you post pom.xml file as well.

Answer (score 28):

It's because of PowerShell that interprets "-" as PowerShell params. ( your terminal shows "PS" in the first line )

so you should escape PowerShell params with --%, like

```
 mvn clean install --% -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command instead.

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Reference Doc - [Maven CheatSheet](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/maven-commands-options-cheat-sheet)

Comment: -DskipTests only skips the test execution, but -Dmaven.test.skip=true will skip the compilation of test classes, too

Answer (score 0):

Can't place this in a comment, not enough rep.

Few things here, the actions described below belong to the Maven Surefire Plugin which you will want to ensure is in the build entries inside your pom

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>x.x.x</version>
      <configuration>
        <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Now you'll have three options to skip tests.

1. As you mentioned use -Dmaven.test.skip this will neither run, nor compile any of your tests meaning anything that relies on test artefacts being available will fail
2. You can use -DskipTests which will compile but not run your tests meaning anything that relies on test artefacts will be able to proceed
3. You can use the configuration property declared above (skipTests), which can be set in your pom properties

Comment: i tried what u say but it doesn't work

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project bankapp: Input length = 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: i have another error

Comment: This is a separate issue, however it should be able to be resolved by specifying your source encoding (most likely UTF-8)

You can do this in the properties section of your pom.xml

`<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>`