# Non-parseable POM Unrecognised tag: 'aifactId'

Tags: pom.xml, artifacts

does anyone know what is going on that is throwing this error in a pom? there is no presence of this tag in any of the poms of all projects and in any of the files of all maven projects... frustrating!

this is the error occur (see the image attached too [aifactId_tag_compile_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHA5E.png)
Non-parseable POM C:\Users\ZEUS\myProjects\myWebapp\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'aifactId' (position: START_TAG seen ...\r\n\t\t... @14:13)

on projects i did right button -> Maven -> Update Project
i have repeatedly updated maven projects with all expected options [update maven project] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/meFtt.png)

I also deleted all .lastUpdate files from .m2/repository to avoid impediments in updating some dependencies, as indicated in this topic
[Maven error "Failure to transfer..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer)