# Project Build Error in Maven while creating webstart project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am getting following error while creating java webstart project using maven in eclipse

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM:Failure to find 
org.jbundle.util.webapp:jbundle-util-webapp-parent:pom:0.7.2 in
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in local respository,
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central
had elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong
local POM.
```

Please help me I am not able to understand what to do

Comment: Could you provide us with the beginning of the pom you are using? It seems you have a problem with  <parent><relativePath> element. It could be pointing to an incorrect or not existing directory or file

Comment: Please see the same issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of

Answer (score 1):

```
The parent pom is not found
1.you can try to remove the parent pom (if you don't have any dependency ) 
2.add the parent pom 

<parent>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
<version>1.5.3-RELEASE</version>
</parent>

root
|-- parent-pom
|   |-- branches
|   |-- tags
|   `-- trunk
|       `-- pom.xml
`-- projectA
    |-- branches
    |-- tags
    `-- trunk
        |-- module1
        |   `-- pom.xml
        |-- moduleN
        |   `-- pom.xml
        `-- pom.xml
```