# My maven build fails when I try to include neo4j-rest-graphdb in my build

Tags: rest, dependencies, neo4j, maven-3

When I try to build my project and include the Neo4j-rest-graphdb dependency the build     fails. I have tried several different versions with the same result.

I have included org.neo4j in my dependencies.

All I really want to do is have an easy way of accessing the graphical local db with my java code.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GraphDatabaseConnector 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing
, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependen
cy information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.375s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Nov 24 22:56:58 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project GraphDatabaseConnector: Could not reso
lve dependencies for project se.morkeleb:GraphDatabaseConnector:jar:0.1: The fol
lowing artifacts could not be resolved: org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb:jar:2.0.0-S
NAPSHOT, org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.neo4j:neo4j-res
t-graphdb:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT in http://m2.neo4j.org was cached in the local repo
sitory, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of neo has
elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of

Comment: recommended release of java-rest-binding for neo4j 2.0 is currently: [2.0.0-M06](http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-rest-graphdb/2.0.0-M06/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was actually pointing to a bad repository that didn't contain the version I wanted to use.

After I added

```
<repository>
        <id>neo4j-release-repository</id>
        <name>Neo4j Maven 2 release repository</name>
        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

It worked out fine when I used milestone 6.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a snapshot release, change the dependency to use a specific Neo4j version. Snapshots are not reliably published, and are not recommended for application development.

Snapshots should only be used if you are committing changes *to* Neo4j, rather than building an application *based on* Neo4j.

Cheers,
Andreas