# Why does pom.xml file give an unknown error

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml

I,m trying to learn spring boot and install spring boot to eclipse IDE. When I create my first project it shows an error in first line of pom.xml. It shows as unknown error.

I tried many solutions from stackoverflow. But none of them work for me.

[Maven pom.xml error in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154022/maven-pom-xml-error-in-eclipse)
[When maven says "resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of MyRepo has elapsed", where is that interval specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of)

My pom.xml as below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Can anyone help me for resolve this.

Comment: Run maven with -X parameter for getting more debug info and share. For e.g., mvn -e -X clean package

Comment: Could you add the error message?

Comment: @akuma8 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory

Comment: What goal did you run and where did you run it? `there is no POM in this directory`

Comment: The error means that you tried to run the maven command within a folder ( project) but there is no pom.xml .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same problem 2 weeks ago. Then, I fixed it with adding a line as below

```
<properties>
    <!-- ... -->
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

And it seems the error was fixed in Eclipse already.
Just **update your Eclipse or STS4.** You may see `m2e connector` is involved in the update list.