# Spring Boot app: Not picking up application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, solr

I have a spring boot app I got here:
https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase/tree/4b3bbf945b182855003d5ba63a60990972a9de72

It compiles and works fine with: `mvn spring-boot:run`

However, when I click "run as Spring Boot app" in Spring Tools Suite, I get an error about not being able to find `${solr.host}` which is set up in the application.properties file.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.data.solr.showcase.product.ProductServiceImpl.setProductRepository(org.springframework.data.solr.showcase.product.ProductRepository); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'solr.host' in string value "${solr.host}"
```

My applications.properties file looks like this:

```
# SPRING MVC
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/

# SOLR
solr.host=http://192.168.56.11:8983/solr
```

The relevant class looks like this (the only place where the $solr.host variable is used).  Also, if I directly address the SOLR server's IP (as in the commented code) the app starts fine.

```
* Copyright 2012 - 2014 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.springframework.data.solr.showcase.config;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.solr.repository.config.EnableSolrRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.solr.server.SolrServerFactory;
import org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.MulticoreSolrServerFactory;

/**
 * @author Christoph Strobl
 */
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = { "org.springframework.data.solr.showcase.product" })

public class SearchContext {

    @Bean
    public SolrServer solrServer(@Value("${solr.host}") String solrHost) {
        return new HttpSolrServer(solrHost);
    }

//  @Bean
//  public SolrServer solrServer(@Value("http://192.168.56.11:8983/solr") String solrHost) {
//      return new HttpSolrServer(solrHost);
//  }

    @Bean
    public SolrServerFactory solrServerFactory(SolrServer solrServer) {
        return new MulticoreSolrServerFactory(solrServer);
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrServerFactory solrServerFactory) {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrServerFactory);
    }

}
```

I'm including that "ProductRepository" -- the one mentioned in the error -- although there isn't much going on there...

```
* Copyright 2012 - 2014 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.springframework.data.solr.showcase.product;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.Query.Operator;
import org.springframework.data.solr.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.solr.repository.SolrCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.solr.showcase.product.model.Product;

/**
 * @author Christoph Strobl
 */
interface ProductRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Product, String> {

    @Query(fields = { SearchableProductDefinition.ID_FIELD_NAME, SearchableProductDefinition.NAME_FIELD_NAME,
            SearchableProductDefinition.PRICE_FIELD_NAME, SearchableProductDefinition.FEATURES_FIELD_NAME,
            SearchableProductDefinition.AVAILABLE_FIELD_NAME }, defaultOperator = Operator.AND)
    Page<Product> findByNameIn(Collection<String> names, Pageable page);

}
```

I've got what seems like a "standard" file structure... code in src/main/java and so on.  The application.properties file resides in src/main/resources.

Any suggestions gratefully accepted.

(Quick addition:  This is running Tomcat as the embedded server)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

This was obscure - and the other answers were very helpful in getting me pointed in the right direction.

After trying the suggested solutions, I poked around deeper and found this in Project Properties --> Java Build Path --> Source(tab) --> Source folders on build path: [Exclusion section]

```
**/application.properties
```

Removing the exclusion fixed the issue and the values were picked up from the application.properties file during startup.

It may be worth noting that running this from the command line (in the directory with the .project file) bypassed the exclusion problem and worked fine.

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Comment: Thank you! Saved my day. I had     <directory>src/main/resources</directory>     <filtering>false</filtering> in pom.xml

Comment: <resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false or true works both - weird</filtering>
    <includes>
     <include>**.*</include>
    </includes>
   </resource>
  </resources>

Comment: Well, slap me silly... it worked. Note, though, that using mvn spring-boot:run did NOT get around the issue for me. FYI.

Comment: Thank you so much! But what in the Nine Hells made the exclusion appear in the first place!?

Comment: Had this weird behaviour for the first time ever when using Eclipse/STS and create ing a project using "New Spring Starter Project"

Comment: Thank you so much, searched for 2h for this solution :/ <3

Answer (score 29):

For me it was due to packaging as **pom**

I had something in my pom.xml as below

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

So if you have similar thing,

1. Remove it for spring-boot App.
2. Delete target folder or mvn clean.
3. then mvn install.
4. Watch your property under target/classes/application.properties file.

Comment: Is there a way to have POM packaging and still have the solution in a working state?

Comment: It seems, it is not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297308/spring-boot-with-pom-packaging-agregator

Comment: thanks , this worked for me, but why this is causes the problem , can you explain ..!

Comment: Packaging 'pom' is used for multimodule projects, since no jar is to be built for module. Other default packaging is 'jar'.

Answer (score 25):

I used *Spring Boot* *2.0.0* and I faced same problem.
With version *1.4.3* it worked perfectly.

**Reason** is that if you define this argument:

```
-Dspring.config.location=file:/app/application-prod.yml
```

*Spring Boot* now is not adding default locations to search.

**Solution**:

```
-Dspring.config.location=file:/app/application-prod.yml,classpath:application.yml
```

See:

1. /org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener.java
2. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix

Comment: This answer appears to be correct. Users should be warned that the documentation (in [Section 76.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-location-of-external-properties)) states (after explaining how to override `spring.config.location`) "No matter what you set in the environment, Spring Boot always loads application.properties as described above." Another option would be to use `spring.config.additional-location` instead.

Comment: This is the correct answer, just helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Include the following in your pom.xml.
This should fix the issue.

```
<build>
    <resources>     
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>                      
                <include>**/*.properties</include>                  
            </includes>
        </resource>            
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: this worked for me, don't forget to `mvn install` after.

Answer (score 9):

Declare the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in your @Configuration class.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {

      return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

And your property resource path with the proper annotation.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:your.properties")
```

Comment: Thanks Dani - this would clearly have worked if my situation had been straightforward.  After trying this to no avail, I kept poking around and found that the directory containing application.configuration had been excluded explicitly in the Project Properties --> Java Build Path --> Source (tab) settings of the project I downloaded.  As soon as I took out the exclusion, the application.properties got read in at startup as you would expect.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, the mentioned approaches didn't help me. Adding Resources folder to **Classpath** solved the issue in my case.

Steps done:

1. select you spring application and open **Run configurations**
2. select **Classpath** tab
3. select **User Entries**
4. click on **Advanced** button
5. select Add Folders and click OK button
6. select your **resources** folder (/src/main/resources) and click OK
   button

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I resolved this by adding resources folder in build path.

Before

[image]

Do the following:-

1. Click on Add folder...
2. Add resources folder

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have some code for importing properties in Spring boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
@EnableScheduling
@ImportResource({ "classpath*:applicationContext.xml" })
@PropertySources(value = {
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value =     "classpath:properties/application.properties"),
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:properties/dbNhibernateConfig.properties"),
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:properties/mailConfiguration.properties"),
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:properties/errorcodes.properties") })
@IntegrationComponentScan("com.*.report.main")
public class AgilereportsApplication{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AgilereportsApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

When a spring boot application is created it reads `application.properties` from the resource folder by default. You don't need to import a property file.

Let say you create another property file with different name or you have moved the `application.properties` file to another folder. In my case I moved property file to *resource\property* folder so I am adding annotation `@PropertySource` to read these property files.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Hi added description.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem. If I did a "Rebuild" from IntelliJ it would copy the application.properties from my src/test/reources folder to my target/test-classes and things would work. But, if I built from Maven, it would disappear from the target/test-classes folder and then the tests would fail when run by maven because it couldn't find the application.properties file. Low and behold, after much back and forth, I realized that my folder was named incorrectly (above is not a typo). I had "src/test/reources/application.properties" instead of "src/test/resources/application.properties". What a pain to spot that. The above answers helped me hone in on it and finally notice the typo. Was not as obvious as one might think. Watch out for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your can always specify where you want spring to look for properties file like so in your pom.xml build section.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/assembly</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/config</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, every time I built just with IntelliJ build, and not with maven command.
finally I found that `application.properties` that located in /target folder is not updated.

Only when I build using maven (even without clean), changes reflected to target folder.

Comment: How should an updated `application.properties` look?

Comment: @parsecer, I meant that I added some changes but they were missing in target folder, only after maven built the file in target folder updated with my changes

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of problem on IntelliJ, I could see the variables wired in the file, but it would not wire it when I launched my SpringBoot app.

I resolved the problem by deleting the `.idea` folder and invalidating cache + restart

Answer (score 1):

Happened when I had to recreate my properties files after deleting them accidentally. Updating maven project worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Adding `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and `@PropertySource` should work in case you want to keep your properties file name as `applications.properties`. However, AFAIK spring boot automatically picks up the`application.properties` file. So, you can also rename your `applications.properties` file to `application.properties` and it should work then.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem it is not loading the application.properties file in class path. In my case the issue was that, if in your resource folder you have more than 1 resources i.e. properties file or xml files then you need to rename the **resource** folder to **resources**. Spring do it automatically for you but if its is not happening do it manually. It solved my issue, might help yours.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the src/test/resources folder, tick the checkbox "Update exclusion filters in other source folders to solve nesting". And also use the PropertySource to load the src

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application-junit.properties"}, 
ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the resource folder was not registered as a resource. I use IntelliJ, so I went to the module settings section, selected the resources folder and then clicked on resource on the upper part of the window. it started taking the application.properties file after that.

Comment: I found this at File>Project Settings>Modules>select a module>Sources tab>Resources sub-tab

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an Encryption Utility class and I was loading public and private keys from the base properties file.

adding **@Component** annotation worked for me.

```
@Component
public class AESEncryption {

private static String BASE64_ENCODED_PUBLIC_KEY;
private static String BASE64_ENCODED_PRIVATE_KEY;

    public AESEncryption(@Value("${BASE64_ENCODED_PUBLIC_KEY}") String BASE64_ENCODED_PUBLIC_KEY,
                         @Value("${BASE64_ENCODED_PRIVATE_KEY}") String BASE64_ENCODED_PRIVATE_KEY) {
        this.BASE64_ENCODED_PUBLIC_KEY = BASE64_ENCODED_PUBLIC_KEY;
        this.BASE64_ENCODED_PRIVATE_KEY = BASE64_ENCODED_PRIVATE_KEY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours and hours this worked!

**Problem**: Springboot 2.X.X ignores application.properties/application.yml and always start the tomcat on default port 8080.

**Root cause**: It is weird from Spring boot 2.x.x and seen in only some machines. Spring docs does not have a concept like this. This is a custom problem.

**Solution**: Provide spring.config.location as classpath:application.properties ( usually we use this practice for external config files but for this issue this works).
Let me know if it also works for you.

Comment: Before you paste this in even more locations, please take the time to read [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions).

Comment: I am new to answering on this platform i understand now how it works in duplicate questions and answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the application properties file and try it. It should detect and compile. It worked for me.

Comment: Rename to what name?

Comment: If your prop file is application.properties, rename it to application1.properties. Define newly renamed filename in your class.

Answer (score -1):

In My case, it was logback-spring.xml. After removing spring in logback filename, it started working.