# Error building java desktop application from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I am trying to build a github project pdfSAM on eclipse. The dependencies are JAVA 8, getText and Maven. I installed all the plugins on eclipse but when I build the project using pom.xml I am getting an error for pdfsam-core project-

"Failed to execute goal on project pdfsam-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.pdfsam:pdfsam-core:jar:3.0.0.RELEASE-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.sejda:sejda-model:jar:2.0.0-alpha13, org.sejda:sejda-conversion:jar:2.0.0-alpha13: Failure to find org.sejda:sejda-model:jar:2.0.0-alpha13 in https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1] "

[Build error on eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbKwG.png)
I also tried building the project from command line using commands

1.mvn clean install

2.mvn clean install -PfastTests

3.mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

All the commands give me me same error and a Build failure occurs.

I am also inserting the pom.xml file of pdfsam-core-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<description>Core pdfsam library</description>
<parent>
 <groupId>org.pdfsam</groupId>
 <artifactId>pdfsam-parent</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.0.RELEASE-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <goals>
       <goal>test-jar</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.pdfsam</groupId>
   <artifactId>pdfsam-i18n</artifactId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
   <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.sejda</groupId>
   <artifactId>sejda-model</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.sejda</groupId>
   <artifactId>sejda-conversion</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.sejda</groupId>
   <artifactId>eventstudio</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>jdepend</groupId>
   <artifactId>jdepend</artifactId>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Kindly give me a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two easy (possible) fixes:

1. Try to delete the artifact in your local repo and rebuild to trigger a download.
2. Use the -U maven goal to update the snapshot.

Top answer from experience, 2nd answer from:
[When maven says "resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of MyRepo has elapsed", where is that interval specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of)