# Springboot Liquibase maven dependency missing

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have been trying to build a springboot project within my virtual desktop and have been facing issues with resolving maven dependencies, after resolving dependencies with improper versions or with incorrect imports, I now have only one dependency conflict that is stopping from compiling the spring boot project that was developed outside my virtual workspacee.

This is what my console says

> The POM for org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:3.3.0 is missing, no dependency information available
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project springboot102: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.css:springboot102:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:3.3.0 in http://repo............/(repository) was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of archiva.default has elapsed or updates are forced ->

Screen shot images also attched as follows :

[image]

If someone had faced similar dependency conflicts please do let me know, much appreciated.

Comment: concerning the warning: apparently [this](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.3.0/liquibase-core-3.3.0.pom) file is missing from the repository or from your local cache as part of the liquibase-core dependency, it's a warning, maven cannot resolve transitive dependencies for it. In your Maven cache, .m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.3.0 folder, you should have the library jar but also the .pom file. Check if they are there and end by lastUpdated. Also, try to re-run the build from console with the -U flag

Comment: also check answers on this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of)

Comment: Also make sure, that the repository which you are connecting to (which seems to be a company internal one) proxies Maven Central and doesn't block for example unapproved Maven artifacts (which is the case in some companies). You should check this with the appropriate administrators.