# Maven: Find where is artifact directory

Tags: maven, artifacts

I am getting the same error as this question: [When maven says "resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of MyRepo has elapsed", where is that interval specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of)

The solution is to delete the particular artifact directory. But how do I find where it is?

Running `mvn clean install -U` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update) does not work for me. It gives error:

```
Could not find artifact <artifact info>... in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

Comment: Your local repo is usually in user's home directory under .m2/repository/, is that what you mean?

Comment: it's not a direct answer to your question, but try `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` (running just this tends to fail the build, so i'm likely missing something..but it seems to successfully delete dependencies from the local repo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default local repo will be in 
`<User_Home>\.m2\repository`

You can check your maven settings.xml to see if there is any custom directory configured.

Comment: Wow, I knew about the .m2 folder, but didn't know that's what they were referring to in the linked question. Deleting the contents of that folder seems to resolve the problem.