# Maven trouble during project creation in Eclipse Mare

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I got the following error message while creating a new Maven project in Eclipse Mare version;

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
Failure to transfer maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central: repo.maven.apache.org
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Have you access to this host: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a your local repository is corrupt, check this previous solutions

- [Force maven update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update)
- [When maven says "resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of MyRepo has elapsed", where is that interval specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of/6127360)