# Eclipse is not downloading plugin from central maven repo

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I am trying to create a JAX-RPC webservice client using `maven-jaxrpc-plugin` in Eclipse using M2E. Here is the corresponding snippet from `pom.xml`

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.sf.jaxrpc-maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxrpc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jax-rpc-scoring-client</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wscompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <config>${project.basedir}/config.xml</config>
                    <operation>gen:client</operation>
                    <mapping>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/jaxrpc-mapping.xml</mapping>
                    <nd>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/wsdl</nd>
                    <d>${project.build.directory}/generated-classes/jaxrpc</d>
                    <keep>true</keep>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</pluginManagement>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>net.sf.jaxrpc-maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxrpc-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

However when I `right click` -> `maven` -> `install`

I get the following error.

```
Plugin net.sf.jaxrpc-maven:maven-jaxrpc-plugin:0.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.sf.jaxrpc-maven:maven-jaxrpc-plugin:jar:0.3: Failure to find net.sf.jaxrpc-maven:maven-jaxrpc-plugin:pom:0.3 in http://fid-nexus.organization.com/ETCB/nexus/content/groups/fid/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I checked on my organisations nexus and the plugin is not there. However shouldn't maven fallback and download it from central repo ? In my m2 `settings.xml` it is configured as shown below.

```
                 <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                    <releases>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
```

I even tried doing right click update on central repository from Maven Repository View but that didn't help. I am really scratching my head on this :(

Comment: Does "mvn clean install" from the command line work?

Comment: how do I do the same in Eclipse ?

Comment: I did it using goals in eclipse wrote clean install, apply and then run. No help.

Comment: The whole point is that you need to get command line maven to work before you can figure out how the m2e emulation fails to do the same.

Comment: I will have a maven installed and check that.

Comment: You should always use command line Maven interchangeably with Eclipse, as Eclipse cannot separate test classes from non-test classes and Maven can.  This may cause your code to break for others.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of

Comment: @karmens89 I have run with -U but no help.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I run "mvn clean install" and got the same error on cmd.

Comment: This sounds like [Eclipse bug 515859](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515859).

Comment: Then You need to learn how repositories work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular library does not exist in the Central Maven Repository nor does it exist any any publicly available repository. It is unreleased code so, as a result, you will be unable to download it regardless of how you configure your POM or Eclipse.

The source for this library exists here (https://github.com/anomen-s/maven-jaxrpc-plugin).

This project expects the user to clone it's Git repository and build it locally, which will place it's artifact in your local Maven cache (i.e., ~/.m2/repository). Once you do this, it will be available to your project.

Instructions on how to build it are in the project's Readme.md file.