# 1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://twitter4j.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository

Tags: maven, pom.xml, twitter4j, snapshot

i have many modules and when i build i get this error, how to fix this error?
jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://twitter4j.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of twitter4j.org has elapsed or updates are force.
help for fix this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--update-snapshots` (or the shorthand `-U`) to force maven to update its snapshots:

```
$ mvn clean install --update-snapshots
```

Comment: Thank you, i try, but i get this Could not find artifact jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in twitter4j.org (http://twitter4j.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]?