# Resolving dependencies in Maven fails

Tags: maven, usergrid

I am trying to deploy Usergrid with the following POM file: https://github.com/apache/usergrid/blob/master/deployment/aws/pom.xml

Initially, I got a bunch of dependency issues so I ran:

```
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins
```

In the output I got some errors and warnings:

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch/maven-metadata.xml from/to codehaus.org (http://repository.codehaus.org): repository.codehaus.org: unknown error
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch/maven-metadata.xml from/to codehaus-snapshots (http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/): nexus.codehaus.org: unknown error
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.usergrid:awscluster:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin @ line 178, column 21
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< org.apache.usergrid:awscluster >-------------------
[INFO] Building awscluster 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:resolve-plugins (default-cli) @ awscluster ---
[INFO] Plugin Resolved: maven-jar-plugin-3.1.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-plugin-api-3.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-core-3.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-artifact-3.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-archiver-3.2.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-archiver-3.5.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar
[INFO] Plugin Resolved: groovy-eclipse-compiler-2.6.0-01.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.350 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-17T13:49:11-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:resolve-plugins (default-cli) on project awscluster: Nested:: Failure to find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch:jar:[1.7.10-02,1.7.10-99],[1.8.2-01,1.9.0) in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I tried downloading and installing the plugin from here:

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch/1.8.2-01
```

Using:

```
$ mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.codehaus.groovy -DartifactId=groovy-eclipse-batch -Dversion=null -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=groovy-eclipse-batch-1.8.2-01.jar
```

I ran `mvn deploy` and still got the dependency error.

How can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch` directory in you local m2 repository like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of)?

Comment: Also: not sure if it's related to the error but maven complains about two declarations of `exec-maven-plugin` in the pom. You should probably move the execution from line 182 into the other existing declaration.

Comment: What do you mean by local m2 repository?

Comment: On you machine you should have a folder probably under `${user.home}/.m2/repository/` where you should check for a folder `org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch`.

Comment: The repositories you have defined `(http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/` are shut down a long time ago...If they are still referenced in project they have not been updated for a long time....

Comment: Okay so I see that it's here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.0.5 but how do I reference that in my POM.xml? In my .m2 directory I don't have a settings.xml. I assume that I need to add something like `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
</dependency>`... is that correct?

Comment: I do not see any of the errors you posted here or in your duplicate question. What is in your `~/.m2/settings.xml`?

Comment: I don't have a settings.xml file in .m2 directory