# Updated Maven dependencies and still getting warnings

Tags: maven, pom.xml, usergrid

I have an old POM file that is referencing dependencies from the now defunct codehaus repository. I have done:

```
$ mvn dependency:resolve AND mvn clean install -U
```

Both return:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from codehaus.org: 
http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from codehaus-snapshots: http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch/maven-metadata.xml from/to codehaus.org (http://repository.codehaus.org): repository.codehaus.org: unknown error
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch/maven-metadata.xml from/to codehaus-snapshots (http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/): nexus.codehaus.org: unknown error
```

If I go to my `~/.ms/repository/org/groovy` I see that the repositories have been updated and the jars are there for `groovy-eclipse-batch` and `groovy-all`.

Is there anything else I need to do? The POM file I am trying to update is located here:

```
https://github.com/apache/usergrid/blob/master/deployment/aws/pom.xml
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving dependencies in Maven fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902752/resolving-dependencies-in-maven-fails)

Comment: Remove the repository definitions from the project...