# Error: Failed to execute goal on projectorg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I tried configuring spring framework in eclipse. And try building a sample. It is giving me the following error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project springBootHelloWorld: Compilation failure
>
> [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project springBootHelloWorld: Could
>   not resolve dependencies for project
>   com.javaInUse:springBootHelloWorld:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following
>   artifacts could not be resolved:
>   org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE,
>   org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   C:\Users\jkalansrayan.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.0.10.RELEASE\aether-f4279e83-b0c7-471b-8dca-f684b2238c2d-spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar-in-progress
>   (The system cannot find the file specified) -> [Help 1]

POM FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.javaInUse</groupId>
<artifactId>springBootHelloWorld</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>springBootHelloWorld</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: I dont know why, just by adding     <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version> it worked :(

Answer (score 2):

1. Check internet connectivity because it may be proxy issue.
2. Remove local maven `.m2` reposiotory folder and do `mvn clean install` again will resolve the issue.

If above solutions don't work then attach the pom.xml file in the question.

Comment: I have attached pom file as you suggested. Thanks,

Comment: did you clear the .m2 repository? if yes then do update maven and check the option "Force update of Snapshots/Releases" in Eclipse. this clears all errors. 
So right click on project -> Maven -> update project, then check the above option -> Ok.

Comment: after updating it is showing error in this part of the pom <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

Comment: Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.javaInUse:springBootHelloWorld:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer 
 org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.6.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local 
 repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.

Comment: have you deleted local maven m2 repository and tried to reinstall using mvn clean install?

Comment: yes i did and even did the update with the check mark"force update snapshots/releases" after okay it is giving me this error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of