# Maven DependencyResoulutionException Error

Tags: maven

I am trying to run apache maven project but encounter with the following problem.

When I try to run `mvn clean install`, it shows this error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project admin: Could not resolve dependencies for project 
com.fengmaotec:admin:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
nl.jworks.markdown_to_asciidoc:markdown_to_asciidoc:jar:1.0, ch.netzwerg:paleo-core:jar:0.11.0: 
Failure to find nl.jworks.markdown_to_asciidoc:markdown_to_asciidoc:jar:1.0 in 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

pom.xml of my project.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fengmaotec</groupId>
    <artifactId>admin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>admin</name>
    <description>fengmaotec admin project for Spring Boot</description>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <mybatis.spring.boot.starter.version>2.1.2</mybatis.spring.boot.starter.version>
        <mybatis.plus.boot.starter.version>3.3.1</mybatis.plus.boot.starter.version>
        <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
        <fastjson.version>1.2.68</fastjson.version>
        <freemarker.version>2.3.29</freemarker.version>
        <ECharts.version>4.7.0.1</ECharts.version>
        <!-- 打包跳过测试 -->
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${mybatis.spring.boot.starter.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!--常用工具类 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${mybatis.plus.boot.starter.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- swagger2-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--防止进入swagger页面报类型转换错误，排除2.9.2中的引用，手动增加1.5.21版本-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- swagger2-UI-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--阿里 FastJson依赖-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>${fastjson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--代码生成器依赖-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--测试-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--    安全框架    -->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.swagger2markup/swagger2markup -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.swagger2markup</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger2markup</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.github.swagger2markup</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger2markup-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--此处端口一定要是当前项目启动所用的端口-->
                    <swaggerInput>http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs?group=api</swaggerInput>
                    <outputDir>src/docs/asciidoc/generated/all</outputDir>
                    <config>
                        <!-- 除了ASCIIDOC之外，还有MARKDOWN和CONFLUENCE_MARKUP可选 -->
                        <swagger2markup.markupLanguage>ASCIIDOC</swagger2markup.markupLanguage>
                    </config>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3</version>
                <!-- Include Asciidoctor PDF for pdf generation -->
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.0-alpha.10.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jruby-complete</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.21</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <!-- Configure generic document generation settings -->
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>src/docs/asciidoc/generated/all</sourceDirectory>
                    <sourceHighlighter>coderay</sourceHighlighter>
                    <attributes>
                        <toc>left</toc>
                    </attributes>
                </configuration>
                <!-- Since each execution can only handle one backend, run
                     separate executions for each desired output type -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>output-html</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html5</backend>
                            <outputDirectory>src/docs/asciidoc/html</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>output-pdf</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>pdf</backend>
                            <outputDirectory>src/docs/asciidoc/pdf</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried what suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of)?

Comment: yes, i tried it. but still get the same error. Can you just specify what part of pom.xml is wrong?

Comment: I don't find any error in it, the log states that maven can't find `nl.jworks.markdown_to_asciidoc:markdown_to_asciidoc:jar:1.0` jar: to prevent local cache you can delete, from your local repository, the related folder (looking at these files you will find the log with the error) and run another maven update, Try also to add https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/ as repository in your pom

Answer (score 1):

First, you can try what suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of).

Then, since that jar ([Maven page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nl.jworks.markdown_to_asciidoc/markdown_to_asciidoc/1.0)), need a specific repository, you could try adding this code in your pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Spring</id>
        <name>Spring</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good point raised in the first sentence!
Unfortunately, the dependencies mentioned above are no longer available in Spring repo :(