# Maven Error in pom.xml using spring template

Tags: java, spring, maven

i am getting the following error in mi maven pom.xml on a spring template project

"Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.slf4j:slf4j-api:pom:1.5.6 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:pom:1.5.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): C:\Users\muhsin.HIFX.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.5.6\slf4j-api-1.5.6.pom.ahc0570cfa3a1934af5 (The system cannot find the file specified)    pom.xml /sample line 1  Maven Dependency Problem"

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jpa-utility</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Spring JPA Utility</name>
    <url>http://www.springframework.org</url>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[This project is a minimal jar utility with Spring configuration for JPA usage.]]>
    </description>
    <properties>
        <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
        <spring.framework.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.156</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>        
        </plugins>
    </build>

 <!--   <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>Codehaus</id>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <downloadUrl>http://www.springframework.org/download</downloadUrl>
        <site>
            <id>staging</id>
            <url>file:///${user.dir}/target/staging/org.springframework.batch.archetype/${pom.artifactId}</url>
        </site>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring Release Repository</name>
            <url>file:///${user.dir}/target/staging/release</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>file:///${user.dir}/target/staging/snapshot</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement> -->
</project>
```

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4650508/1213738) will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the error message

> "Description Resource Path Location Type ArtifactDescriptorException:
>   Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:
>   ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer
>   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:pom:1.5.6 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
>   was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are
>   forced.

it means you have to delete the folder $HOME/.m2/repository/org/slf4j and afterwards you need to rebuild via

```
mvn clean package
```

and other given error message:

> Original error: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:pom:1.5.6 from/to central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   C:\Users\muhsin.HIFX.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.5.6\slf4j-api-1.5.6.pom.ahc0570cfa3a1934af5
>   (The system cannot find the file specified) pom.xml /sample line 1
>   Maven Dependency Problem"

indicates that you have some kind of problem with you repository access. Either you have a proxy which is not correctly configured. What i recommend is to use a repository manager which makes life easier.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use force update flag(-U) for example:

```
 mvn clean install -U
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can try to run maven clean to perform a clean
2. You can manually navigate to the specified file in your local repository and remove it and then try to download it as afresh copy using mvn clean install -e

Answer (score 1):

open this location
C:\Users...m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-surefire-plugin\2.10
Delete the file maven-surefire-plugin-2.10 and build the project.

it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the files present inside the folder **C:\Users\username.m2\repository**
open eclipse again rebuild the project - (Give some time for eclipse IDE to Build the Workspace).

Answer (score 0):

<maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>

add this line in the properties. Worked for me!