# Nexus: Could not find artifact

Tags: maven, caching, repository, nexus

Recently I've migrated from Archiva to Sonatype Nexus.

I'm trying to use Jars from 3rd party repositories and Nexus does not cache it into the local repository.

I've searched for answers in this section and couldn't one that answers the question.

Here is what I did...

I'm using settings.xml :

```xml
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://THE_URL:8080/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>admin</id>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>

        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>

      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

I've also created proxy repositories for all the 3rd party repositories I'm using, and ADDED THEM TO THE NEXUS PUBLIC GROUP.

Next, I've run the command:

```
mvn clean install
```

and got the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building shlang 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://THE_URL:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/com/shadow/shadow/1/shadow-1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.341s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jun 30 11:59:42 IDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/120M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project shlang: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.shadow:shlang:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [couchbase:couchbase-client:jar:1.1.5 (compile), com.google.code.gson:gson:pom:2.2.2 (compile), org.json:json:jar:20090211 (compile), net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4 (compile), jline:jline:jar:2.10 (compile), commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.4.0 (compile), spy:spymemcached:jar:2.8.1 (compile), com.shadow:util:jar:1.0.1 (compile), com.shadow:monkey_schoolyard:jar:1.0.0 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.shadow:util:jar:1.0.1: Could not find artifact com.shadow:shadow:pom:1 in nexus (http://THE_URL:8080/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

The result in the local repo is that it does not contained any of the 3rd party jars it should.

What do I miss here?

Comment: You've configured the "public" repository group as a mirror of "*". This means that is the goto URL for all your Maven artifacts. Can all the artifacts you're trying to retrieve be obtained from that group URL? I'm guessing not.

Comment: You seemed to be missing the repository for the artifact `couchbase-client` which is not in Maven central. So you have to change the configuration for your public repository which means adding the repository which contains the above dependencies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Could not resolve dependencies, artifacts could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650460/maven-could-not-resolve-dependencies-artifacts-could-not-be-resolved)

Answer (score 11):

Most likely your local Maven repository has the fact that the component can not be found cached. You can force Maven to check for updates of snapshot versions and existence of previously not found version with the -U flag.

So run

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Sometimes if thing are really weird it can help to completely delete the respective folder structure in your local repository. So in your example

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/com/shadow/
```

Answer (score 8):

If Manfred's solution does not work for you, then the issue will be with Nexus trying to resolve the artifact.

If you use a browser you can check what Nexus is actually doing to locate the artifact you are after.

Append **?describe** to the url of the Nexus repository with the path of the artifact.

E.g.
Nexus Repository Public Repositories URL: http://my.nexus.server.address:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/

Fetching the artifact

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Path of the above artifact would be: **org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar**

So the full URL to check

> http://my.nexus.server.address:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar?describe

This process will then proceed through the list of repositories configured under your Public Repositories group in the order that the repositories are specified, indicating why a repository was unable to provide the requested artifact.

Most reasons are pretty self-explanatory and can be ignored.

One reason that may be of interest is when the error **is still cached as not found for repository** is retrieved for a repository.

This indicates that at some point Nexus has tried to retrieve the artifact and failed to locate it.

This status seems to be cached within Nexus, so the quickest way to clean out the cache is to *restart Nexus*.

Comment: That's exactly what happened to our server, at some point a connectivity issue prevented it from retrieving an artefact from maven-central, and the only way to fix this was to restart the service. I tried the "Invalidate Cache" button from administration but it did not help, And I find the settings page really hard to read. Any hint on a parameter that would reset this cache at some point ? Is it linked to default 1440 minutes value ?

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, make sure that your pom and XML tags are clean of invisible characters (strip special chars, copy from a standard source like mvnrepository.com, retype manually, whatever).

I had a tricky invisible character corrupting my nexus lookup (only from the maven build) and spent an embarrassing amount of time debugging it since everything else I tried worked fine.

---

Here was my example (revealed by http://www.nousphere.net/cleanspecial.php):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
    <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
    <version>&#8206;7.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

See that junk hiding in front of the version?

Answer (score 0):

If the repo link is not working or blocked, try the mirrors. Most of artifacts are available on other mirrors.

Add a mirror to nexus-private.hortonworks.com in '/.m2/settings.xml' in local root directory(in case of centOS). There are many maven mirror bases out there like

- maven-central
- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
- https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com
- https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/  etc......

I would suggest to use "https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/" in this case.  Add following to '*/.m2/settings.xml*'

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>alternate</id>
        <name>alternate to hortonworks</name>
        <mirrorOf>*,!central</mirrorOf>
        <url>https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

This adds the mirror to all repos except central. So central would not be affected and hortonworks is mirrored.

Also, if working on **PROXY**, dont forget to add it in *mvn command* ; use this

```
mvn clean install -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=<your proxy host> -DproxyPort=<port>
```

Used this while Ambari installation, worked. Hope this solves:).