# Weblogic Maven Deploy with Luna eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, weblogic12c

**I am using weblogic 12.1.1.0 . I want to deploy my project to weblogic server with maven plugin.
But when I build my project, I get this error**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:jar:12.1.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:12.1.1.0: Plugin com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:12.1.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:jar:12.1.1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test1 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:jar:12.1.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:12.1.1.0: Plugin com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:12.1.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:jar:12.1.1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5:deploy (default-cli) @ test1 ---
[WARNING] The POM for weblogic:weblogic:jar:10.3.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for weblogic:webservices:jar:10.3.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.533 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-27T08:38:04+03:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5:deploy (default-cli) on project test1: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5:deploy failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: weblogic:weblogic:jar:10.3.6, weblogic:webservices:jar:10.3.6: Failure to find weblogic:weblogic:jar:10.3.6 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

**and this is my pom.xml**

```
<properties>
      <weblogic.adminurl>t3://localhost:7001</weblogic.adminurl>
      <weblogic.user>weblogic</weblogic.user>
      <weblogic.password>12345678</weblogic.password>
      <weblogic.remote>false</weblogic.remote>

  </properties>

  <build> 
  <plugins> 


  <!-- WebLogic Server 12c Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>

                <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
                <artifactId>wls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>12.1.1.0</version>



                <configuration>
                    <adminurl>${weblogic.adminurl}</adminurl>
                    <user>${weblogic.user}</user>
                    <password>${weblogic.password}</password>
                    <source>../test1/target/test1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</source> 
                    <name>test1</name> 

                </configuration>
            </plugin>



  </plugins> 
  </build>
```

**i added two jar file in project wlfullclient.jar and webservices.jar**

Comment: The weblogic jars exist in your Oracle install dir like `/opt/ora/mw`. You need to add them to your classpath

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven Could not resolve dependencies, artifacts could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650460/maven-could-not-resolve-dependencies-artifacts-could-not-be-resolved)

Answer (score 1):

Have you run the setup procedures for Oracle's weblogic plugin? The plugin has dependencies that are not in public repositories, they are part of the wls12 installation and must be installed into Maven

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm#CHEIHIEH