# Could not resolve dependencies, Failure to find jar

Tags: eclipse, maven, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-charts

I'm trying to run vaadin-charts-demo.

Similar issue to this:
[Maven Could not resolve dependencies, artifacts could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650460/maven-could-not-resolve-dependencies-artifacts-could-not-be-resolved)

```
[INFO] <<< vaadin-maven-plugin:7.4.6:compile (default-cli) < process-resources @ vaadin-charts-demo <<<
[WARNING] The POM for com.vaadin.demo:vaadin-charts-examples:jar:3.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.414 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-09T20:57:33-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/225M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project vaadin-charts-demo: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.vaadin.demo:vaadin-charts-demo:war:3.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.vaadin.demo:vaadin-charts-examples:jar:3.0-SNAPSHOT in https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vaadin-addons has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

pom.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<parent>
    <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-charts-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.vaadin.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>vaadin-charts-demo</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Vaadin Charts Demo</name>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-charts</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.demo</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-charts-examples</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Vaadin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.13.v20130916</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>googleanalyticstracker</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.6.0.alpha2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/config.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/config.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>**/gwt-unitCache/*,**/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**/*</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- As we are doing "inplace" GWT compilation, ensure the widgetset -->
        <!-- directory is cleaned properly -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                <!-- We are doing "inplace" but into subdir VAADIN/widgetsets.
                    This way compatible with Vaadin eclipse plugin. -->
                <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                </webappDirectory>
                <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/target/ignore/VAADIN/widgetsets
                </hostedWebapp>
                <noServer>true</noServer>
                <!-- Remove draftCompile when project is ready -->
                <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                <!-- <style>PRETTY</style> -->
                <strict>true</strict>
                <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-widgetset-on-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Tried googling vaadin-chart-examples and chart-demos maven, repository, etc., but haven't found a solution. How can this be resolved?

[[edit]]
The project is imported from here:
https://github.com/vaadin/charts/tree/7a55e8dab5b9941a05603c2624a576866e86045d

Following these instructions:
https://github.com/vaadin/charts/blob/7a55e8dab5b9941a05603c2624a576866e86045d/DevInstructions.md

After install, couldn't compile widgets

The instructions are for Luna, I'm using Mars, not sure how that affects things.

Comment: How did you set up the project initially? Where did you get the information from to add this dependency? Why is the question tagged with _eclipse?_ There's no reference to it in the question.

Comment: I added edits - the warning/error came up when I tried to compile widgets

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding this repository for Vaadin add-ons:

```
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
```

Comment: Yes, it didn't work.  It also has another project folder as one of its dependencies, and the pom for that has the repository.  Does that means that they are connected/related/it's the same as if it were in the current project pom?

Comment: @newMAD Apparently, you still need to add all dependencies to both poms. Check [this link](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-add-a-project-as-a-dependency-of-another-project.html?page=1) for linking projects via maven dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you built just `vaadin-charts-demo` so far build `vaadin-charts-parent` before, as well.

[The parent includes `vaadin-charts-examples` as `<module>`.](https://github.com/vaadin/charts/blob/7a55e8dab5b9941a05603c2624a576866e86045d/pom.xml) So, if you don't build `parent` (or `examples` explicitely) at least once, none of the modules' artifacts is available in your Eclipse workspace and your local Maven repo to be resolved from there.

Remember, [Aggregation and Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book//reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit) are different types of [POM Relationships](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#POM_Relationships).

For resolving dependencies from your Eclipse workspace see <*Your Eclipse Maven project*> → *Properties* → *Maven* → [✔] *Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects.*