# Missing artifact maven

Tags: java, maven

I have the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

in my pom file but it shows error saying.

```
Missing artifact javax.servlet:com.springsource.javax.servlet:jar:2.5.0
```

The below are the repositories that i used in my pom file

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle
            Releases
            </name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle
            Releases
        </name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Could you include your repositories?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven Could not resolve dependencies, artifacts could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650460/maven-could-not-resolve-dependencies-artifacts-could-not-be-resolved)

Comment: Update artifactId to: <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Please note that this artefact has usually the scope "provided"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what happened but the m2 got screwed up as it created many m2 subfolders in m2. when i changed it. The Error was resolved, thanks for the quick reply guys.