# Could not resolve dependencies for project. Could not find artifact.

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a problem with building a project Farma-rest which depends on my other project Farma. I put dependency in my pom.xml but it couldn't resolve dependencies for the project. It shows me this error message:

Failed to execute goal on project Farma-rest: Could not resolve dependencies for project sk.upjs.ics:Farma-rest:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact sk.upjs.ics:Farma:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

Here is the pom of the first project:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sk.upjs.ics</groupId>
    <artifactId>Farma</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.8-dmr</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.44.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
            <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

And here is the POM of the project which I want to build:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sk.upjs.ics</groupId>
    <artifactId>Farma-rest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.8-dmr</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>sk.upjs.ics</groupId>
            <artifactId>Farma</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <!-- <scope>compile</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried to clean and build the project but it didn't helped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Could not resolve dependencies, artifacts could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650460/maven-could-not-resolve-dependencies-artifacts-could-not-be-resolved)

Comment: Excuse me, but did you verify if the Farma jar is installed in your local maven repository?

Comment: which is obviously not the case as @AndrePiantino wrote...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jar for the **Farma** project is not available in your local maven repo.

1. Check if the `~/.m2/repository/sk.upjs.ics/Farma/1.0-SNAPSHOT` directory exists. It should not at this point.
2. Run the build for the **Farma** project. Maven should create the artifact and put it in your local maven repository.
3. Check the same directory as before. It should now exist and it should have a jar and pom in it.
4. Now try building **Farma-rest** again and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realised, that some unit tests weren't working in project Farma so maven couldn't build jar and put it in my local maven repository. I fixed it, so now it is working.

Comment: @tomas123 can you elaborate on that? I'm having the same issue