# How can I call classes from other projects with Maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar, war

I'm fairly new to Java and I can't figure out how to properly call classes from another projects using Maven to do something like this:

```
import AnotherProjectClass;

public class Jade {
     public void exampleFunction(){ 

          AnotherProjectClass apc = new AnotherProjectClass();
          apc.smth();
     }
}
```

I'm using NetBeans and have three projects. Two of them are Web applications (as seen here [Web Applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEIw7.jpg)) and the main one is a Java application, all with Maven.

In both Web Applications I have used the maven-war-plugin to build the .jar file when building the .war file. Following the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31220514

Next I added both .jar files as dependencies to the main Java application project following these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340440 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/48452297

I can successfully build the main project, but I can't call anything from the other two projects, although they appear in the dependencies tab.
[Dependencies from main project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kTLU.jpg)

My `pom.xml` from the main project (maven_tese_lima) is like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.limatese</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven_tese_lima</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tilab.jade</groupId>
            <artifactId>jade</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.protege.editor.owl.codegeneration</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.limatese</groupId>
            <artifactId>tese_maven_REST_nextstep</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <classifier>classes</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.limatese</groupId>
            <artifactId>tese_maven_REST_state</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <classifier>classes</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Don't try to use WAR projects (Web projects) as dependencies. If you want to have common code, build a `common` JAR as separate project and use it as dependency in the other projects.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @JFabianMeier. I will try to do this following your tip!