# Maven artifact not found in central

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to use this `Maven` dependency for a project https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.ecf.protocol/bittorrent/0.3.0
I used the declaration in my `pom.xml`, when I update the project it could not resolve dependency from this https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ URL.

[image: Maven Error screenshot]

So I looked up the page and [there](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/) was no `Bittorent` jar there. Can anyone explain me why this jar is missing from the maven2 repo and how to resolve this error. I tried other answers but nothing works for this one.

Comment: Please do not paste images of error logs. Simply cop/paste the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other ways for an author to host their jars in their public website. But I'm not sure why dependency resolving error occurs in this repo, when I figure out I'll edit this answer to include it.
Until then You can download the jar from files section of the repository page and include it in your class path to solve this issue for now.

here's the [link to file](https://www.jabylon.org/maven/org/eclipse/ecf/protocol/bittorrent/0.3.0/bittorrent-0.3.0.jar)

Comment: This jar solution works for me. It would be more useful if the maven dependency resolves too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This artifact is not hosted on the maven central repository (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/), but rather on: https://www.jabylon.org/maven/

You can double-check this by navigating to: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.ecf.protocol/bittorrent

[image]

---

In your case, the solution is to [add the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650460/maven-could-not-resolve-dependencies-artifacts-could-not-be-resolved) to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <!-- ... -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.ecf.protocol</groupId>
      <artifactId>bittorrent</artifactId>
      <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>Jabylon</id>
      <url>https://www.jabylon.org/maven/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  May I know why they didn't add repository tag in the original pom.xml in mvn central, if it isn't the one hosting the jar? New users like me are going to copy paste to our pom.xml dependency section thinking that it'll work.