# Hudson build fail: Non-resolvable parent POM

Tags: build, maven, hudson, parent, pom.xml

I used to work with Hudson on my project, and lately I had to move it to a new server.

I configured it the exact same way it use to be (for all I can tell) but when I try to launch a build, it fails and I get the following error:

```
Démarré par l'utilisateur anonymous
Checking out http://[...]/trunk/MyProject/ear
A         .classpath
A         .project
A         target
AU        target/ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear
A         target/application.xml
A         target/ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT
A         target/ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/META-INF
A         target/ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/META-INF/application.xml
AU        target/ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
AU        target/ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/business-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
A         pom.xml
A         .settings
A         .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
A         .settings/org.maven.ide.eclipse.prefs
At revision 136
no change for http://[...]/trunk/MyProject/ear since the previous build
Found mavenVersion 3.0.2 from file jar:file:/usr/share/maven/apache-maven-3.0.2/lib/maven-core-3.0.2.jar!/META-INF/maven/org.apache.maven/maven-core/pom.properties
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Echec à la lecture des POMs
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.rha:MyProject:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 9, column 10

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:325)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:360)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.readProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:330)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1148)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:991)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:756)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:738)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:698)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:420)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1362)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:405)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
Finished: FAILURE
```

The pom.xml file when I got to Hudson "workspace" looks like this:

[...]

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.rha</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

[...]

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rha</groupId>
            <artifactId>business</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rha</groupId>
            <artifactId>web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**[Edit]**

Actually I forgot some important informations:

My project is divided into 3 parts:

business (packaged into .jar)
web (packaged into a .war)
ear (packaged the .war and .jar into a .ear)

I'm using Subversion, and under my "trunk" folder I got a "MyProject" folder including:

```
.project
.settings/
business/
ear/
pom.xml
src/
web/
```

what happens is:

in my Hudson job configuration, I filled the SVN field "repository URL" with:

> http://[...]/trunk/MyProject/ear

and here is the "pom.xml" from "MyProject" folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 

[...]
    <modules>
        <module>business</module>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>ear</module>
    </modules>
[...]
```

so the parent "pom.xml" is actually located at "../pom.xml" on my SVN repository, under "trunk/MyFolder".

But Hudson can't see it for some reason (but like I said, it used to work on the previous server).

Any clue ?

**[/Edit]**

I guess this is a rookie mistake, I'm a total beginner on Maven, but I just can't figure out why it's not working anymore ...

Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Nicolas

Comment: So do you only have one pom file? You should have two if you have a reference to parent pom file. Right? Also don't check the target directory in svn.

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: see my edit =)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`relativePath` (of the `parent`) defaults to `../pom.xml`.  It looks like it is not present in there. You could set it to an empty value so that maven downloads it as a dependency.

```
 <relativePath/>
```

[This link](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/mvn-3-parent-relativePath-problem-but-no-relativePath-element-td3278463.html) discusses this.

[Edit: based on the edits to the question]

Hudson only sees the source code inside ear folder.  Though the parent pom is present in SVN, it is not available to Hudson.  Missing parent pom was aa warning in Maven 2 but [strict](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Iron+Fist+of+Maven+3.0+transition+pack#IronFistofMaven3.0transitionpack-relativepathtoparent) in Maven 3.

There are two ways to solve this.

One is to specify to hudson, the url `http://[...]/trunk/MyProject/`.  You can then chose to build all the modules or still choose to build the `pom.xml` of ear project alone.

The other is to manually run `mvn install` on the hudson system so that the parent pom gets deployed once and thereafter used by hudson.  However, this will not get updated if parent pom is subsequently changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer ! I change the URL to ` http://[...]/trunk/MyProject/` so now I can see 3 modules. I went to the "ear" module and configure Maven goal to `clean package cargo:redeploy -P integration` but when trying to build, I got the following: `[...] <===[HUDSON REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Finished: ABORTED`. It basically build nothing =/

Comment: I eventually went for the `mvn install` method. It does work but I don't like the fact that the parent pom.xml can't be updated ... thanks a lot anyway !

Comment: A work around for the parent pom.xml update problem is to have a jenkins maven job that just install it and is triggered like any other jobs, as a bonus if the parent pom is updated all dependent job will be rebuild as well

Comment: This answer saved me lots of time. Just had a similar issue with the Spring in Action examples. I copied them to my Eclipse Workspace, but didn't notice the parent POM, which was in the folder above them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which explained what is happening. Our solution was to delete some files from the jenkins server .m2 repository (see separate answer).

Answer (score 4):

Retrieving the Root-POM from the Maven-REPO should usually also work (like you do), but I would expect you havn't triggered the root pom to be installed into the REPO on the new hudson site so far.

To avoid this use the relativePath property, e.g. something like this:

```
<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
```

in your `<parent>` tag which will tell maven to look for the root pom in your module structure.

Comment: I tried it, and I still got an error: `[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.rha:MyProject:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 9, column 10`

Comment: As the error message says: the relativePath property is set to a wrong path, e.g. if your pom is  in /home/test/project/moduleA and your root pom is in /home/test/project/ then you add "../pom.xml" as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Hudson, Sonar plugin and a multi-module Maven project: "Non-resolvable parent POM" when Hudson tried to run sonar:sonar. The solution was to specify the Root POM location in the Hudson job configuration under the Sonar section.

The project structure in SVN (each one is a Maven project with pom.xml in the project root):

```
foo-parent
  +- foo-ui-module
  +- bar-other-module
```

I have individual Hudson jobs for each project, "foo-parent", "foo-ui-module" and "bar-other-module". The Sonar run in a Hudson job could not find the parent POM even though the build was successful until that point. Maybe the Sonar plugin doesn't use the same Maven settings as the rest of the job because it didn't try to look for the parent POM from our Artifactory repository, not even with `<relativePath/>` in the project POM.

The place for the Root POM setting was under the job's Configure -> Sonar -> Advanced -> Root POM: `../foo-parent/pom.xml` (I have foo-parent job at this path)

Answer (score 0):

We managed to get this working by simply deleting the relevant pom file, plus some sort of metadata file with a similar name in the same folder, from the `.m2/repository/a/b/c` folder on our jenkins server.

Rerunning the jenkins build after doing this worked just fine.

Hope this helps someone...