# pom.xml Can't resolve parent?

Tags: java, xml, file, jar, pom.xml

I am a "noob" with maven and I am running a mvn clean install for a open source project I found. I am trying to get it to build a jar file. When I run it the way it "supposedly" is going to work. I get this error...

```
Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact
com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk:monkeytalk:pom:1.0.12-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath'
points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 10 -> [Help 2]
```

For the pom.xml file @ line 6-10 I have...

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk</groupId>
    <artifactId>monkeytalk</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Is there a step I am missing? I can give more code if you need it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can answer any question you have if you need more info!

Comment: You, probably, did not configure access to SNAPSHOT repository of the artifact in question.

Comment: No I did not configure that. How would I go about doing that? Sorry I am very "noob" with xaml files and maven.

Comment: don't know much, but check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170758/hudson-build-fail-non-resolvable-parent-pom

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Are you sure you have a proper project layout? I mean, do you have the parent pom.xml in one directory above this pom? If not, can you try `<relativePath>../som/dir//pom.xml</relativePath>`?

Comment: Darn... That didn't work. Can you vote up so people will see?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the parent projects pom.

Most likely your folder structure looks like this:

```
.../moneytalk_Foo/pom.xml
.../moneytalk_Foo/someFolder
```

but it should look like this:

```
.../pom.xml
.../moneytalk_Foo/pom.xml
.../moneytalk_Foo/someFolder
```

Or that parent is a project into itself and you must download it and call `mvn install` on it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

the parent project maybe not installed yet, try run the parent project "monkeytalk" as Maven install.

[image: how to install the parent project in eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a cure all for everyone seeing this, but for me it was because my maven  settings.xml file was not being found. Maven uses this file to locate remote repos for downloading SNAPSHOT files so if it can't find the settings.xml file then parent.relativePath is essentially undefined. Pretty crappy error message for this IMO, it should dump the value of parent.relativePath to give some indication of an undefined var.