# Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact

Tags: java, maven, build, jar, agent

I have recently looked into [Gorilla Logic's](http://gorillalogic.com)  open source testing tool and need to make some changes in order to be able to log something to the console. I have checked out the code out of source control for the "Android Agent" and now I am looking to build a new .jar agent file. I need to use the 
   `mvn clean install` to build the .jar file. When I try to build it the command line is giving this error 
`Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk:monkeytalk:pom:1.0.12-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 10 -> [Help 2]`

Can anyone help me with this or let me know what this means? Thanks. :)
I don't understand maven and just want to know what it means.

Here is the pom.xml file line 6-10

```
<parent> 
<groupId>com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk</groupId>
    <artifactId>monkeytalk</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>/Users/henry/Desktop/monkeytalk-agent-android/parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Comment: Is this (http://stackoverflow.com/q/11658497/839527)  useful?

Comment: That didn't seem to resolve my problem.. O.o

Comment: Is that the relative or absolute path to where your parent pom.xml is? Any file path starting with "/" looks like an absolute path.

Answer (score 6):

This project seems to be module project under another maven project "moneytalk".
As this project can inherit properties, dependency management information, plugin information from the parent project, maven tries to read the parent pom.xml. 
If the parent pom.xml is not available at the specified location, maven build will fail.

One option is to checkout all the projects including the parent project.
Other option is to place the pom.xml of the parent project at the required location (in your case /Users/henry/Desktop/monkeytalk-agent-android/parent/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks. :) When I created the new parent folder it failed because it couldn't find the pom file. Is there any more steps?

Comment: ...The project was "monkeytalk"... NOT "moneytalk"... ;p

Answer (score 0):

If there are lots of dependencies behind the project, they have to be pattered for first before building the main project.

Clean, compile and install such dependencies (from the "Maven" pane found on the right side of the IDE). First move such dependencies enclosed within their projects to the same main project directory.

Lastly, clean, compile and install the main project.