# Non-resolvable parent POM for Could not find artifact and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Tags: build, maven-3, packaging, pom.xml

I am new to maven.

I have one project which I try to build with the maven3.

When I run the command `mvn -X clean install` I got the error.

```
[root@localhost]# mvn -X clean install
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 14:14:56+0530)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_24, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/maven/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /root/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /root/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for /root/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.test.ctrl:ctrl-build:0.0.17-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (/root/.m2/repository)
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.openstack:openstack-rhel-rpms:2012.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test.ctrl:ctrl-build:pom:0.0.17-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ org.openstack:openstack-rhel-rpms:2012.1-SNAPSHOT, /root/test/devenv/openstack-rhel/pom.xml, line 8, column 13

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:636)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:585)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:234)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.openstack:my-tar:2012.1-SNAPSHOT (/root/test/devenv/mytar/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.openstack:openstack-rhel-rpms:2012.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test.ctrl:ctrl-build:pom:0.0.17-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ org.openstack:openstack-rhel-rpms:2012.1-SNAPSHOT, /root/test/devenv/openstack-rhel/pom.xml, line 8, column 13 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact com.test.ctrl:ctrl-build:pom:0.0.17-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:813)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:664)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:310)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:232)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:410)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:379)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:343)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:636)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:585)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:234)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.test.ctrl:ctrl-build:pom:0.0.17-SNAPSHOT
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:155)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.test.ctrl:ctrl-build:pom:0.0.17-SNAPSHOT
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:528)
        ... 26 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I check the `pom.xml` but cant understand what was the problem.
Some lines from my `pom.xml` is as below.

```
  1 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  2 <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  3     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  4   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  5
  6 <parent>
  7     <groupId>org.openstack</groupId>
  8     <artifactId>openstack-rhel-rpms</artifactId>
  9     <version>2012.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 10     <relativePath>../openstack-rhel</relativePath>
 11 </parent>
 12
 13     <groupId>org.openstack</groupId>
 14     <artifactId>my-tar</artifactId>
 15     <version>2012.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 16   <packaging>pom</packaging>
 17   <name>my tar</name>
 18
```

I also check the solution on some question in stackoverflow like [Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677734/non-resolvable-parent-pom-could-not-find-artifact) but couldnt help to solve the problem.

If you need more information related to this question, let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have the file `/root/test/devenv/openstack-rhel/pom.xml`

This file need to have the followings elements:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.openstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>openstack-rhel-rpms</artifactId>
    <version>2012.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

Comment: Don't start creating files with (semi)random content. The main issue here is that maven needs to resolve the parent pom. That must happen either from remote repositories (check your ~/.m2/settings.xml for that) or locally (either in local repo ~/.m2/repository or at a location relative to the current project's directory and specified by <relativePath/> tag value which defaults to "..").

Answer (score 25):

I faced the same issue. Setting relative path of the parent in module projects solved the issue.

Use `<relativePath>../Parent Project Name/pom.xml</relativePath>`

Answer (score 3):

I encountered an issue like this using the Maven Release Plugin. Resolving using relative paths (i.e. for the parent pom in the child module ../parent/pom.xml) did not seem to work in this scenario, it keeps looking for the released parent pom in the Nexus repository. Moving the parent pom to the parent folder of the module resolved this.

Comment: its quick solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have settings.xml. I had the same problem when I've deleted it by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Any way you mentioned /root/.m2/settings.xml.

But in my Case i missed the settings.xml to configure in the maven preferences.
[image] so that maven will search for the relative_path pom.xml from the remote_repository which is configured in settings.xml

Answer (score 2):

In pom.xml file of the project,

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>X.X.X.RELEASE</version>
<relativePath> ../PROJECTNAME/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Pointing relativepath to the same MAVEN project POM file solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the reason was a simple typo.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.sringframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

A missing character in the `groupId` org.s(p)ringframework lead to this error.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue.

The parent pom file was available in our local repository, but maven still unsuccessfully tried to download it from the central repository, or from the *relativePath* (there were no files in the relative path).

Turns out, there was a file called *"_remote.repositories"* in the local repository, which was causing this behavior. After deleting all the files with this name from the complete local repository, we could build our modules.

Answer (score 1):

Give the relative path URL value to the pom.xml file
../parentfoldername/pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to enter [proxy configuration to maven](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies) settings file and run mvn verify from command line. Somehow eclipse was still givin the same timeout error when trying to download the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

may help some one, after 2 hours of unsuccessful research of the problem just did svn clean up and it helped.