# create maven project failing

Tags: maven-3, eclipse-kepler

whenever I am trying to build my maven project it is giving error saying:

```
Non-resolvable parent POM:the artifact is not available in the local repository and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 10
```

I am using local repository. and running maven in offline mode

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677734/non-resolvable-parent-pom-could-not-find-artifact

Comment: can you post your pom.xml files and where they are located in the file structure?