# Where can I obtain the maven-source-plugin?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, maven-source-plugin

I checked out an open-source project from SourceForge's SVN source control using the Eclipse Maven plugin. After it checks out, I get this error in the pom.xml file:

> Error resolving version for plugin
>   'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin' from the repositories
>   [local (C:\Documents and Settings\thomas.owens\.m2\repository),
>   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any
>   plugin repository

I'm fairly new to Maven, but I followed the installation instructions for Apache Maven and the Eclipse plugin. It seems weird that this plugin would not be found in the central plugin repository for Maven or my local repository, when I can clearly see a directory located at `C:\Documents and Settings\thomas.owens\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-source-plugin` that contains a single `resolver-status.properties` file.

Any thoughts as to why this plugin might not be found and where I can find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem that I was encountering was not an issue with the maven-source-plugin, but incorrect proxy settings that was preventing the connection to the repositories. The [answers to this question on the use of Maven with a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy) helped me to find the mistake and correct it.

Answer (score 7):

That plugin is in the [central repository](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.maven.plugins%7Cmaven-source-plugin%7C2.1.2%7Cmaven-plugin).

Perhaps you just need to run with -U to update:

```
mvn -U clean install
```

Or in Eclipse: right-click on the project, select Maven-> Update Dependencies, (perhaps) Maven-> Update Project Configuration

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are able to see Maven in Eclipse, Window > Preferences.

If so, select Maven and go to installations and check if the folder, in where maven was installed, is properly set. Then, set your setting.xml file, it should be in /(maven installation folder)/conf/

Then, right click in your project go to Maven > Update Maven Dependencies.

Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

Which project?
Perhaps there is a bug in their pom.
Or perhaps they require a 'standardized' develop environment with specific environment variables set, or a specific setting in user.home/.m2/settings.xml