# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM in maven

Tags: pom.xml

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM guide.ide.eclipse:guide-ide-eclipses:1.0-SNAPSHOT for guide.ide.eclipse:guide-ide-eclipse:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to resolve POM for guide.ide.eclipse:guide-ide-eclipses:1.0-SNAPSHOT due to Missing:

---

### 1) guide.ide.eclipse:guide-ide-eclipses:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT

1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  guide.ide.eclipse:guide-ide-eclipses:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)

Answer (score 2):

Bit late in answering this but... as I've been bitten this afternoon by something similar...

Have you checked out [How do I use Maven through a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy/7823304#7823304)

The answers there are pretty helpful and relate to proxy issues which may relate to your problem. My own answer there relates to "parent not found" and "parent.relativeParent points to wrong local POM" errors where the parent pom actually resides in a remote repository. I've documented the various attempts I made to resolve this issue (with credits), ultimately changing how I configured the proxy for maven.

Answer (score -1):

My friend was getting the same error. Actually he was connected to his companies VPN. He just disconnected with the VPN and then force updated the project and it started working fine.