# Getting error while creating simple maven project

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

getting error while creating simple maven project

```
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'org.apache.maven.plugins' could not be retrieved from repository: central due to an error: Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
[INFO] Repository 'central' will be blacklisted
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
```

Comment: are you using any proxy to connect to internet? Or are you behind a firewall?

Comment: we are using proxyy to connect to internet ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check your internet connection (but you posted here somehow, so I guess it's OK).

Then take a look at [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) about user settings; if you're behind a firewall/NAT, then you probably need to add proxy definition inside the `<proxy>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy/1251216#1251216) on how to **connect to maven from a proxy**. Try updating after that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that your organization firewall/proxy prohibits downloading of jars. You can verify that by trying to download the jars through a browser.  If you get an error, then you may want to work with your IT folks to fix it.