# How do I configure maven to use Tor?

Tags: maven, proxy, tor

I have looked at the documentation for proxy settings (specifcally the [proxy mini-howto](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)) in order to use maven with Tor. When I try to connect to Tor with the default port 9050, there is an error in the Tor message center that states *Warning: Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy)*. How do I configure maven to work through tor?

(Also note that the suggestions at the Stackoverflow question [How do I use maven through a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy) were not succesful)

Answer (score 1):

Since tor is not an HTTP proxy (like you commonly find in corporate environments) you have to specify the [Java networking properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html) for SOCKS proxies on the command line.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5455495/7507) to the question you linked to.